# Performance (FPS) issue when displaying a video inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm facing an issue, I have 2 videos

Each frame I display a video inside a canvas like this.

```
button.onclick = () => {
    if (
        video.src ===
        "https://github.com/Treast/javascript-dronie/blob/master/src/app/videos/circleButtonScaling.mp4?raw=true"
    ) {
        video.src =
            "https://github.com/Treast/javascript-dronie/blob/master/src/app/videos/circleButtonPulsing.mp4?raw=true";
    } else {
        video.src =
            "https://github.com/Treast/javascript-dronie/blob/master/src/app/videos/circleButtonScaling.mp4?raw=true";
    }

    video.play();
};

let video = document.createElement("video");
video.muted = true;
video.loop = true;

video.src =
    "https://github.com/Treast/javascript-dronie/blob/master/src/app/videos/circleButtonPulsing.mp4?raw=true";

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 1280, 720);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();

video.play();
```

My issue is that with one of the two video it's smooth 60fps but when I swap video, the framerate drops dramatically

You can try it out here https://4j83wy06n9.codesandbox.io/

I really don't understand what's going on